# When does garbage collection get triggered in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I read many things about garbage collection like it's generation, scope etc but want to know when does the garbage collection gets triggered ?
an example will be really helpful if possible.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't  have enough points, @MikeNakis :)

Comment: It would be helpful to know *why* you want to know. The GC does a collection when it feels like it's a good time to do a collection; its internal policies are not part of the documented, guaranteed behavior. If you're just curious, that's one thing. If you intend to develop software that depends on a particular GC policy, you are skating on some pretty thin ice.

Comment: @EricLippert - recently i was asked this question in interview..so want to know.

Answer (score 21):

Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is true:

- The system has low physical memory.
- The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process runs.
- The `GC.Collect` method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and testing.

Source: [Fundamentals of garbage collection - Conditions for a garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#conditions-for-a-garbage-collection)

Comment: so.. does clr check for physical memory at regular intervals in program  and if it is low , GC is called  ?

Comment: Most probably, yes. If Microsoft says that GC is called when the system has low memory, the CLR should be notified or checking if the memory is low.

Answer (score 1):

1. Automatically when the application is unable to acquire memory from
   managed heap
2. Automatically when a given `AppDomain` unloads from memory
3. through code when `GC.Collect()` called

Answer (score 0):

You are not in control of `GC` and can not reliably predict its behavior. 
All calls, like `GC.Collect` are simple *messages* to VM to start collection, but that does not mean that collection *will* eventually start right after the line.