# Does Out of Memory exception triggers Garbage Collection?

Tags: c#, .net

If a program encounters a Out of Memory for any reasons, will Garbage collection kicks in by default ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does garbage collection get triggered in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461652/when-does-garbage-collection-get-triggered-in-c)

Comment: I know when garbage collection happens etc. The question was inverse in nature. A program can cause Out of memory exception. Will Garbage collection kicks in at that time ?

Comment: If a program suffers an OutOfMemoryException, I think you have far bigger problems to worry about than whether GC gets invoked.

Comment: Typically the sequence would be that you attempt an allocation, there's not enough free memory available, GC runs, there's *still not enough free memory*, the exception is thrown. It's a catastrophic failure which indicates the runtime has already exhausted all options, including GC.

Comment: no, GC doesn't care for that exception. However when the exception is unhandled and your app crashed, the entire memory of the associated app-domain surely will be relased (at least the unmanaged stuff)

Comment: @rajibdotnet what does your code do? That's where the problem is, not GC. In most cases OOMs are thrown by inefficient code that generates so many orphaned objects, especially arrays, that RAM becomes fragmented to the point that there's no RAM block big enough to allocate the next big array.

Comment: @rajibdotnet most containers use a T[] buffer internally. When that's full, a new one with twice the size is allocated. If you add N items to a List<T> one by one, you end up creating log2(N) buffers and using twice the RAM you really need. Do that for 10K, 1M items, and you end up with OOMs. The easy solution is to specify a capacity when you create the list. Even a wild guess can reduce reallocations a *lot*. Another solution is to reuse preallocated arrays and buffers providede by ArrayPool and MemoryPool

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This question came out of curiosity. I don't have a situation at hand like this. I tried some findings before I posed this question but people are more eager to award negative ratings rather than understanding the sentiments.

Comment: No, the query forces people to guess and makes it impossible to write a good answer. I didn't downvote. You should check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)